# Make my Neo4j queries faster

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm evaluating Neo4j for our application, and now am at a point where performance is an issue. I've created a lot of nodes and edges that I'm doing some queries against. The following is a detail of the nodes and edges data in this database:

[image: Detail of nodes/edges in database]

I am trying to do a search that traverses the yellow arrows of this diagram. What I have so far is the following query:

```
MATCH (n:LABEL_TYPE_Project {id:'14'})
    -[:RELATIONSHIP_scopes*1]->(m:LABEL_TYPE_PermissionNode)
    -[:RELATIONSHIP_observedBy*1]->(o:LABEL_TYPE_Item)
WHERE m.id IN ['1', '2', '6', '12', '12064', '19614', '19742', '19863', '21453', '21454', '21457', '21657', '21658', '31123', '31127', '31130', '47691', '55603', '55650', '56026', '56028', '56029', '56050', '56052', '85383', '85406', '85615', '105665', '1035242', '1035243']
   AND o.content =~ '.*some string.*'
RETURN o
LIMIT 20
```

**(The variable paths above have been updated, see "Update 2")**

The above query takes a barely-acceptable 1200ms. It only returns the requested 20 items. If I want a count of the same, this takes forever:

```
MATCH ... more of the same ...
RETURN count(o)
```

The above query takes many minutes. This is Neo4j 2.2.0-M03 Community running on CentOS. There is around 385,000 nodes, 170,000 of type Item.

I have created indices on all `id` fields (programmatically, `index().forNodes(...).add(...)`), also on the content field (`CREATE INDEX ...` statement).

Are there fundamental improvements yet to be made to my queries? Things I can try?

Much appreciated.

*This question was moved over from Neo4j discussion group on Google per their suggestions.*

---

## Update 1

As requested:

```
:schema
```

Gives:

```
Indexes
  ON :LABEL_TYPE_Item(id)             ONLINE  
  ON :LABEL_TYPE_Item(active)         ONLINE  
  ON :LABEL_TYPE_Item(content)        ONLINE  
  ON :LABEL_TYPE_PermissionNode(id)   ONLINE  
  ON :LABEL_TYPE_Project(id)          ONLINE  

No constraints
```

**(This is updated, see "Update 2")**

---

## Update 2

I have made the following noteworthy improvements to the query:

- Shame on me, I did have super-nodes for all `TYPE_Project`s (not by design, just messed up the importing algorithm that I was using) and I removed it now
- I had a lot of "strings" that could have been proper data types, such as integers, booleans and I am now importing them as such (you'll see in the updated queries below that I removed a lot of quotes)
- As pointed out, I had variable length paths and I fixed those
- As pointed out, I should have had uniqueness indices instead of regular indices and I fixed that

As a consequence:

```
:schema
```

Now gives:

```
Indexes
  ON :LABEL_TYPE_Item(active)         ONLINE                             
  ON :LABEL_TYPE_Item(content)        ONLINE                             
  ON :LABEL_TYPE_Item(id)             ONLINE (for uniqueness constraint) 
  ON :LABEL_TYPE_PermissionNode(id)   ONLINE (for uniqueness constraint) 
  ON :LABEL_TYPE_Project(id)          ONLINE (for uniqueness constraint) 

Constraints
  ON (label_type_item:LABEL_TYPE_Item) ASSERT label_type_item.id IS UNIQUE
  ON (label_type_project:LABEL_TYPE_Project) ASSERT label_type_project.id IS UNIQUE
  ON (label_type_permissionnode:LABEL_TYPE_PermissionNode) ASSERT label_type_permissionnode.id IS UNIQUE
```

The query now looks like this:

```
MATCH (n:LABEL_TYPE_Project {id:14})
   -[:RELATIONSHIP_scopes]->(m:LABEL_TYPE_PermissionNode)
   -[:RELATIONSHIP_observedBy]->(o:LABEL_TYPE_Item)
WHERE m.id IN [1, 2, 6, 12, 12064, 19614, 19742, 19863, 21453, 21454, 21457, 21657, 21658, 31123, 31127, 31130, 47691, 55603, 55650, 56026, 56028, 56029, 56050, 56052, 85383, 85406, 85615, 105665, 1035242, 1035243]
   AND o.content =~ '.*some string.*'
RETURN o
LIMIT 20
```

The above query now takes approx. 350ms.

I still want a count of the same:

```
MATCH ...
RETURN count(0)
```

The above query now takes approx. 1100ms. Although that's much better, and barely acceptable for this particular query, I've already found some more-complex queries that inherently take longer. So a further improvement on this query here would be great.

As requested here is the `PROFILE` for `RETURN o` query (for the improved query):

```
Compiler CYPHER 2.2

Planner COST

Projection
  |
  +Limit
    |
    +Filter(0)
      |
      +Expand(All)(0)
        |
        +Filter(1)
          |
          +Expand(All)(1)
            |
            +NodeUniqueIndexSeek

+---------------------+---------------+-------+--------+-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|            Operator | EstimatedRows |  Rows | DbHits | Identifiers |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            Other |
+---------------------+---------------+-------+--------+-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|          Projection |          1900 |    20 |      0 |     m, n, o |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                o |
|               Limit |          1900 |    20 |      0 |     m, n, o |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    {  AUTOINT32} |
|           Filter(0) |          1900 |    20 | 131925 |     m, n, o |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  (hasLabel(o:LABEL_TYPE_Item) AND Property(o,content(23)) ~= /{  AUTOSTRING31}/) |
|      Expand(All)(0) |          4993 | 43975 |  43993 |     m, n, o |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              (m)-[:RELATIONSHIP_observedBy]->(o) |
|           Filter(1) |             2 |    18 |    614 |        m, n | (hasLabel(m:LABEL_TYPE_PermissionNode) AND any(-_-INNER-_- in Collection(List({  AUTOINT1}, {  AUTOINT2}, {  AUTOINT3}, {  AUTOINT4}, {  AUTOINT5}, {  AUTOINT6}, {  AUTOINT7}, {  AUTOINT8}, {  AUTOINT9}, {  AUTOINT10}, {  AUTOINT11}, {  AUTOINT12}, {  AUTOINT13}, {  AUTOINT14}, {  AUTOINT15}, {  AUTOINT16}, {  AUTOINT17}, {  AUTOINT18}, {  AUTOINT19}, {  AUTOINT20}, {  AUTOINT21}, {  AUTOINT22}, {  AUTOINT23}, {  AUTOINT24}, {  AUTOINT25}, {  AUTOINT26}, {  AUTOINT27}, {  AUTOINT28}, {  AUTOINT29}, {  AUTOINT30})) where Property(m,id(0)) == -_-INNER-_-)) |
|      Expand(All)(1) |            11 |    18 |     19 |        m, n |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  (n)-[:RELATIONSHIP_scopes]->(m) |
| NodeUniqueIndexSeek |             1 |     1 |      1 |           n |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          :LABEL_TYPE_Project(id) |
+---------------------+---------------+-------+--------+-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

And here is the `PROFILE` for `RETURN count(o)` query (for the improved query):

```
Compiler CYPHER 2.2

Planner COST

Limit
  |
  +EagerAggregation
    |
    +Filter(0)
      |
      +Expand(All)(0)
        |
        +Filter(1)
          |
          +Expand(All)(1)
            |
            +NodeUniqueIndexSeek

+---------------------+---------------+--------+--------+-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|            Operator | EstimatedRows |   Rows | DbHits | Identifiers |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            Other |
+---------------------+---------------+--------+--------+-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|               Limit |            44 |      1 |      0 |    count(o) |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    {  AUTOINT32} |
|    EagerAggregation |            44 |      1 |      0 |    count(o) |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  |
|           Filter(0) |          1900 |    101 | 440565 |     m, n, o |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  (hasLabel(o:LABEL_TYPE_Item) AND Property(o,content(23)) ~= /{  AUTOSTRING31}/) |
|      Expand(All)(0) |          4993 | 146855 | 146881 |     m, n, o |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              (m)-[:RELATIONSHIP_observedBy]->(o) |
|           Filter(1) |             2 |     26 |    850 |        m, n | (hasLabel(m:LABEL_TYPE_PermissionNode) AND any(-_-INNER-_- in Collection(List({  AUTOINT1}, {  AUTOINT2}, {  AUTOINT3}, {  AUTOINT4}, {  AUTOINT5}, {  AUTOINT6}, {  AUTOINT7}, {  AUTOINT8}, {  AUTOINT9}, {  AUTOINT10}, {  AUTOINT11}, {  AUTOINT12}, {  AUTOINT13}, {  AUTOINT14}, {  AUTOINT15}, {  AUTOINT16}, {  AUTOINT17}, {  AUTOINT18}, {  AUTOINT19}, {  AUTOINT20}, {  AUTOINT21}, {  AUTOINT22}, {  AUTOINT23}, {  AUTOINT24}, {  AUTOINT25}, {  AUTOINT26}, {  AUTOINT27}, {  AUTOINT28}, {  AUTOINT29}, {  AUTOINT30})) where Property(m,id(0)) == -_-INNER-_-)) |
|      Expand(All)(1) |            11 |     26 |     27 |        m, n |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  (n)-[:RELATIONSHIP_scopes]->(m) |
| NodeUniqueIndexSeek |             1 |      1 |      1 |           n |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          :LABEL_TYPE_Project(id) |
+---------------------+---------------+--------+--------+-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Remaining suggestions:

- Use `MATCH ... WITH x MATCH ...->(x)` syntax: this did not help me at all, so far
- Use [Lucene indexes](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/indexing-lucene-extras.html): still *to do* **See results in "Update 3"**
- Use precomputation: this will not help me, since the queries are going to be rather variant

---

## Update 3

I've been playing with full-text search, and indexed the `content` property as follows:

```
IndexManager indexManager = getGraphDb().index();
Map<String, String> customConfiguration = MapUtil.stringMap(IndexManager.PROVIDER, "lucene", "type", "fulltext");
Index<Node> index = indexManager.forNodes("INDEX_FULL_TEXT_content_Item", customConfiguration);
index.add(node, "content", value);
```

When I run the following query this takes approx. 1200ms:

```
START o=node:INDEX_FULL_TEXT_content_Item("content:*some string*")
MATCH (n:LABEL_TYPE_Project {id:14})
   -[:RELATIONSHIP_scopes]->(m:LABEL_TYPE_PermissionNode)
   -[:RELATIONSHIP_observedBy]->(o:LABEL_TYPE_Item)
WHERE m.id IN [1, 2, 6, 12, 12064, 19614, 19742, 19863, 21453, 21454, 21457, 21657, 21658, 31123, 31127, 31130, 47691, 55603, 55650, 56026, 56028, 56029, 56050, 56052, 85383, 85406, 85615, 105665, 1035242, 1035243]
RETURN count(o);
```

Here is the `PROFILE` for this query:

```
Compiler CYPHER 2.2

Planner COST

EagerAggregation
  |
  +Filter(0)
    |
    +Expand(All)(0)
      |
      +NodeHashJoin
        |
        +Filter(1)
        |  |
        |  +NodeByIndexQuery
        |
        +Expand(All)(1)
           |
           +NodeUniqueIndexSeek

+---------------------+---------------+--------+--------+-------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|            Operator | EstimatedRows |   Rows | DbHits | Identifiers |                                                                  Other |
+---------------------+---------------+--------+--------+-------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|    EagerAggregation |            50 |      1 |      0 |    count(o) |                                                                        |
|           Filter(0) |          2533 |    166 |    498 |     m, n, o | (Property(n,id(0)) == {  AUTOINT0} AND hasLabel(n:LABEL_TYPE_Project)) |
|      Expand(All)(0) |         32933 |    166 |    332 |     m, n, o |                                        (m)<-[:RELATIONSHIP_scopes]-(n) |
|        NodeHashJoin |         32933 |    166 |      0 |        m, o |                                                                      o |
|           Filter(1) |             1 |    553 |    553 |           o |                                            hasLabel(o:LABEL_TYPE_Item) |
|    NodeByIndexQuery |             1 |    553 |    554 |           o |               Literal(content:*itzndby*); INDEX_FULL_TEXT_content_Item |
|      Expand(All)(1) |         64914 | 146855 | 146881 |        m, o |                                    (m)-[:RELATIONSHIP_observedBy]->(o) |
| NodeUniqueIndexSeek |            27 |     26 |     30 |           m |                                         :LABEL_TYPE_PermissionNode(id) |
+---------------------+---------------+--------+--------+-------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Can you also share the profiling output?

Comment: And remove the varlength paths, you don't need them here.

Comment: I've updated the question on basis of your and other people's feedback! All feedback much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Things to think about/try:  in general with query optimization, the #1 name of the game is to figure out ways to consider less data in the first place, in the answering of the query.  It's far less fruitful to consider the same data faster, than it is to consider less data.

- [Lucene indexes](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/indexing-lucene-extras.html) on your `content` fields.  My understanding is that regex you're doing isn't narrowing cypher's search path any, so it's basically having to look at every `o:LABEL_TYPE_Item` and run the regex against that field.  Your regex is only looking for a substring though, so lucene may help cut down the number of nodes cypher has to consider before it can give you a result.
- Your relationship paths are variable length, (`-[:RELATIONSHIP_scopes*1]->`) yet the image you give us suggests you only ever need one hop.  On both relationship hops, depending on how your graph is structured (and how much data you have) you might be looking through way more information than you need to there.  Consider those relationship hops and your data model carefully; can you replace with `-[:RELATIONSHIP_scopes]->` instead?   Note that you have a `WHERE` clause on `m` nodes, you may be traversing more of those than required.
- Check the query plan (via `PROFILE`, google for docs).  One trick I see a lot of people using is pushing the most restrictive part of their query to the top, in front of a `WITH` block.  This reduces the number of "starting points".

What I mean is taking this query...

```
MATCH (foo)-[:stuff*]->(bar)   // (bunch of other complex stuff)
WHERE bar.id = 5
RETURN foo
```

And turning it into this:

```
MATCH bar
WHERE bar.id = 5
WITH bar
MATCH (foo)-[:stuff*]->(bar)
RETURN foo;
```

(Check output via `PROFILE`, this trick can be used to force the query execution plan to do the most selective thing first, drastically reducing the amount of the graph that cypher considers/traverses...better performance)

- Precompute; if you have a particular set of nodes that you use all the time (those with the IDs you identify) you can create a custom index node of your own.  Let's call it `(foo:SpecialIndex { label: "My Nifty Index" })`.  This is akin to a "view" in a relational database.  You link the stuff you want to access quickly to `foo`.  Then your query, instead of having that big `WHERE id IN [blah blah]` clause, it simply looks up `foo:SpecialIndex`, traverses to the hit points, then goes from there.  This trick works well when the list of entry points in your list of IDs is large, rapidly growing, or both.   This keeps all the same computation you'd do normally, but shifts some of it to be done ahead of time so you don't do it every time you run the query.
- Got any supernodes in that graph?  (A supernode is an extremely densely connected node, i.e. one with a million outbound relationships) -- don't do that.  Try to arrange your data model such that you don't have supernodes, if at all possible.
- [JVM/Node Cache tweaks](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/configuration-caches.html).  Sometimes you can get an advantage by changing your node caching strategy, or available memory to do the caching.  The idea here is that instead of hitting data on disk, if you warm your cache up then you get at least some of the I/O out of the way.  This one can help in some cases, but it wouldn't be my first stop unless the way you've configured the JVM or neo4j is already somewhat memory-poor.  This one probably also helps you a little less because it tries to make your current access pattern faster, rather than improving your actual access pattern.

Comment: Thank you. Interestingly the `RELATIONSHIP_someRelationship*1` make my query about ten times faster than `RELATIONSHIP_someRelationship`. Still, I misread the documentation originally on this, and have now moved to `RELATIONSHIP_someRelationship*..1` which gives the same results as `RELATIONSHIP_someRelationship*1` did for me.

Answer (score 1):

can you share your output of :schema in the browser?

if you don't have it do:

```
create constraint on (p:LABEL_TYPE_Project) assert p.id is unique;
create constraint on (m:LABEL_TYPE_PermissionNode) assert m.id is unique;
```

The manual indexes you created only help for `Item.content` if you index it with FULLTEXT_CONFIG and then use `START o=node:items("content:(some string)") MATCH ...`

As in Neo4j you can always traverse relationships in both directions, you don't need the inverse relationships, it only hurts performance because queries then tend to check one cycle more.

You don't need variable length paths `[*1]` in your query, change it to:

```
MATCH (n:LABEL_TYPE_Project {id:'14'})-[:RELATIONSHIP_scopes]->
      (m:LABEL_TYPE_PermissionNode)-[:RELATIONSHIP_observedBy]->(o:LABEL_TYPE_Item)
WHERE m.id in ['1', '2', ... '1035242', '1035243']
AND o.content =~ '.*itzndby.*' RETURN o LIMIT 20
```

For real queries use parameters, for project-id and permission.id ->

```
MATCH (n:LABEL_TYPE_Project {id: {p_id}})-[:RELATIONSHIP_scopes]->(m:LABEL_TYPE_PermissionNode)-[:RELATIONSHIP_observedBy]->(o:LABEL_TYPE_Item) 
WHERE m.id in {m_ids} AND o.content =~ '.*'+{item_content}+'.*'
RETURN o LIMIT 20
```

remember a realistic query performance only shows up on a warmed up system, so run the query at least twice

you might also want to split up your query

```
MATCH (n:LABEL_TYPE_Project {id: {p_id}})-[:RELATIONSHIP_scopes]->(m:LABEL_TYPE_PermissionNode)
WHERE m.id in {m_ids} 
              WITH distinct m
              MATCH (m)-[:RELATIONSHIP_observedBy]->(o:LABEL_TYPE_Item) 
WHERE o.content =~ '.*'+{item_content}+'.*'
RETURN o LIMIT 20
```

Also learn about `PROFILE` you can prefix your query it in the old webadmin: http://localhost:7474/webadmin/#/console/

If you use Neo4j 2.2-M03 there is built in support for query plan visualization with `EXPLAIN` and `PROFILE` prefixes.